# How to Get the Current Selected Node in Virtual Tree View

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I am using Delphi XE3 with Virtual Tree View. If multiselect is False, how to get the current selected node in the virtual tree view. I find in document, and there is a related method:

TBasedVirtualTree.Selected[]: This requires a PVirtualNode  as the index to get the selection status.

But will not give out the node that is selected currently.

I will describe the process how I try to find out the solution:

1. Firstly, I try to search in Virtual TreeView's help document, with the keyword "Selected". Then I will get 71 results. Among them I find TBaseVirtualTree.Selected property, but this requires PVirtualNode as the index.
2. Then in the top-right corner of the help document, I try to find related properties, but can only find SearchBuffer and SelectedCount, the former is unrelated, the latter is get the selected node count, not the current selected node.
3. This is also a function that can get an array of selected nodes. However, when I try to call it, I find it is not available.

That is the reason why I post this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declared in `TBaseVirtualTree`:

`function GetFirstSelected(ConsiderChildrenAbove: Boolean = False): PVirtualNode;`

Note that you may have several selected nodes, and to get to the other ones call

`function GetNextSelected(Node: PVirtualNode; ConsiderChildrenAbove: Boolean = False): PVirtualNode;`